# Is it possible to train a model when I have just one class labbeled?

Tags: machine-learning, semi-supervised-learning

I have a large dataset (~1,700,000) which I would like to binary classify. I also have a not that small sample (~8,000) classified as one of those classes (let's say TRUE condition), but I have none (zero) of the other class (FALSE condition). All my variables are categorical.

Am I abble to train the model with just the TRUE observations? If not, how should I overcome this issue? Is it reasonable to randomly take a few of the not classifed observations and supose it is the FALSE condition?

**EDIT**

There are lots of diferent groups, let's say from A to Z, and I'm just interested in group A. That's why I divided it in TRUE x FALSE and the know the most of it are not in group A (or TRUE in the binary approach).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that all the unlabeled data are FALSEs?

Comment: I have no reason to believe all of them are FALSE, but surely the most of them are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I abble to train the model with just the TRUE observations? If not, how should I overcome this issue? Is it reasonable to randomly take a few of the not classifed observations and supose it is the FALSE condition?

We don't know anything about your unlabeled (not classified) data, maybe 90% of the unlabeled data should have a TRUE label, if that is the case then it would be a bad idea to assume that they are FALSE.

One thing you can do is to perform unsupervised learning (e.g. cluster analysis) with all of your data combined. Look at the number of TRUE samples in each cluster and find the cluster with the highest percent of TRUE samples. This can be used as a binary classifier, if a future observation is in the cluster with many TRUE samples then it can be classified as TRUE.